# Converting Sentinel 2 jp2 bands to TIFF with gdal

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to convert a .jp2 file from the Sentinel 2 project to .tif with gdal. For some bands it works (e.g. B01) and for some bands it always fails (e.g. B04). I use the sentinel public image browser data (e.g [this product](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/32/U/QC/2018/5/24/0/)).

When I run `gdal_translate B04.jp2 B04.tif` I get the following output:

> Input file size is 10980, 10980
>   0maximum number of samples exceeded (120560400 > 67108864)
>   error: cannot decode code stream
>   ERROR 1: B04.jp2, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0

My gdal version is 2.3.0, released 2018/05/04

Comment: Converting file B04.jp2 works for me with GDAL 2.4.0dev and the OpenJPEG driver. Which JPEG 2000 drivers do you have? Check with `gdalinfo --formats`.

Comment: JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF \n
    JPEG2000 -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1), based on Jasper library

Comment: There is no issue in conversion of B04.jp2 to B04.tif using the above command. I used gdal 2.3.0 released 2018/05/04. It worked well. Try opening the data in a viewer. It might be corrupted.

Comment: Jasper driver is useless. Find GDAL version that is compiled with some good driver: OpenJPEG, JP2ECW, Kakadu, or JP2MrSID.

Comment: I used Homebrew to install GDAL (`brew install gdal --with-complete`). I don't know how to change the JP2 drivers. I tried the gdal docker image (geodata/gdal) which comes with GDAL 2.3.0dev, released 2017/99/99 and has the JP2OpenJPEG driver. Everything works with that combination.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in conversion of B04.jp2 (you posted in question) to B04.tif using the above command.

I used gdal 2.3.0 released 2018/05/04. It worked well.

Try opening the data in a viewer. It might be corrupted/not fully download.

The error **IReadBlock failed** generally occurs when the file is not complete.

Comment: GDAL version is not important. GDAL is reading and writing data through drivers and for JPEG 2000 there are many drivers available. OpenJPEG driver page http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2openjpeg.html has links to other JPEG 2000 drivers. Jasper cannot be recommended for handling big geospatial images. Only reason to have it in GDAL is that it is open source.